# Viewing Word Documents in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to programming viewing word documents in WPF I using this code 
I have this error int this line `public partial class MainWindow : Window`
the message show 'Window' is an ambiguous reference between ' System.Windows.Window' and '  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.window'. how can correct it ?

```
private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".doc";
    dlg.Filter = "Word documents (.doc)|*.doc";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
    if (result == true)
    {
        if (dlg.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            SelectedFileTextBox.Text = dlg.FileName;
            string newXPSDocumentName =
    String.Concat(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName), "\\",
                            System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dlg.FileName), ".xps");

            // Set DocumentViewer.Document to XPS document
            documentViewer1.Document =
                ConvertWordDocToXPSDoc(dlg.FileName, 
    newXPSDocumentName).GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do individuals refuse to use google as a tool or reference 
take a look here [C# Viewing Word Documents in WPF](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20viewing%20word%20documents%20in%20wpf)

Comment: @DJKRAZE The title is just bad. It really doesn't have anything to do with the question at hand.

Comment: you have to fully qualify the namespace that you are using `Application` is a key word that can be noticed in windows as well as in Microsoft.Interop as well as OleAutomation meaning Microsoft applications. or `Window`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias Word's `Window` class.

```
using WordWindow = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window;
using Window = System.Windows.Window;
```

Then change where you are using `Window`from Word to use the new alias `WordWindow`.

An example of where it goes:

```
...
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using WordWindow = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window;
using Window = System.Windows.Window;
```

Comment: I did not understand the meaning where should I put this ,please

Comment: @rose, It goes under the rest of your `using` statements. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: @rose I have updated my answer. I forgot about needing to specify which `Window` you wanted to use by default.